# How to set attribute names in template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I have a vector class :

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2 {
    public:
      T x, y;
    Vector2(T x, T, y) : x{x}, y{y} {}
}
```

And I would like get different accessors depending on the context:

```
Vector2<float, x, y> xy;
xy.x = 42;

Vector2<float, u, v> uv;
uv.u = 42;
```

Is something like that possible in C++? More specifically, is this possible in C++03?

### Context

I work on an embedded firmware in C++ for a DC/DC voltage converter. I have different values such as voltages, current... Some transformations can be applied from a 3-phase current (u,v,w) into 2-phase static (a,b) and 2-phase rotating frame (d, q). It would be more readable to have specific types such as:

```
using CurrentDQ = Vector2<float, d, q>
using CurrentAB = Vector2<float, a, b>
using Current3 = Vector<float, u, v, w>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can do is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct ElemsUV {T u, v;};

template <typename T>
struct Vector : T {};

Vector<ElemsUV<float>> vec;

// Or:
// template <typename T, template <typename> class E> struct Vector : E<T> {};
// Vector<float, ElemsUV> vec;
```

You can of course split `u` and `v` into separate structures, but a single big one looks more convenient to me.

Then the `Elems??` structures would have a uniform interface for `Vector<...>` to interact with, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct ElemsUV
{
    T u, v;
    T &get_x() {return u;}
    T &get_y() {return v;}
};
```

And `Vector` would internally use only `get_x()`, `get_y()` to access the element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about C++03 but you can have `unions` to access the same data with different variables.
You could create your stuct like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2 {
public:
    union
    {
        T x, u;
    };
    union
    {
        T y, v;
    };
    Vector2(T x, T y) : x{ x }, y{ y } {}
};
```

and then access the data like this:

```
Vector2<int> vec(1, 2);
vec.x;
vec.u;
```

and they will both have the same value/address.

Comment: I used to do it like this, but it causes problems. For example, this won't compile if you use a non-trivial-destructible type as `T` (e.g. `std::string`), `Vector2` needs an explicit destructor. I'm now convinced that the best way is `T x; T &u() {return x;}`.

Comment: "you can have unions to access the same data with different variables" generally no, but I think in this case yes, though depends on what `T` is.